# Encoder and canonicalize in ESAPI

Tags: java, esapi

I understand what ESAPI is used for, but I see these two lines repeated in a lot of ESAPI examples. Can someone please explain what exactly this does?

```
ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(inputUrl,false,false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#canonicalize(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)):

> Canonicalization is simply the operation of reducing a possibly
>   encoded string down to its simplest form. This is important, because
>   attackers frequently use encoding to change their input in a way that
>   will bypass validation filters, but still be interpreted properly by
>   the target of the attack. Note that data encoded more than once is not
>   something that a normal user would generate and should be regarded as
>   an attack.

The two additional parameters which are set to false in your example indicate whether or not to restrict multiple encoding and mixed encoding (see docs for meaning), respectively.

Comment: Hi, I also need to use the `encoder.encodeForHTML(String)`. So should I do the **canonicalization** first or the `encodeForHTML()` first? What should be my order?

Comment: FYI: new link for documentation:
https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#canonicalize(java.lang.String)